# How do I find out what program ranger is using to preview a file?

Tags: ranger

I am using the [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/) terminal based file manager to navigate and view files.
When I navigate to a folder which contains pdf files, and position the cursor on a PDF file ranger reads the file  and then displays it in its preview pane .

[image]

My understanding is that the ranger program delegates to "rifle" the tasks of

- recognising what type of file it is - in this case PDF
- launching a program which handles that filetype
- instructing the program to load the file currently under the cursor

I now want to open the file being previewed in the text based program that is rendering the preview in the above image.  However when I press <kbd>l</kbd> to launch ranger/rifle uses  "evince", a GUI program.
Looking in

file: `~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf`

```
#-------------------------------------------
# Documents
#-------------------------------------------
ext pdf, has llpp,     X, flag f = llpp "$@"
ext pdf, has zathura,  X, flag f = zathura -- "$@"
ext pdf, has mupdf,    X, flag f = mupdf -- "$@"
ext pdf, has apvlv,    X, flag f = apvlv -- "$@"
ext pdf, has xpdf,     X, flag f = xpdf -- "$@"
ext pdf, has evince,   X, flag f = evince -- "$@"
ext pdf, has atril,    X, flag f = atril -- "$@"
ext pdf, has okular,   X, flag f = okular -- "$@"
ext pdf, has epdfview, X, flag f = epdfview -- "$@"
ext pdf, has qpdfview, X, flag f = qpdfview "$@"
```

This configuration indicates that `evince` will be used when a file is "opened" but what program is being used to generate the preview?

- I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [webpage](http://ranger.nongnu.org/), it uses [`pdftotext`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) for pdf previews.  (You could read the source code to be certain).

Comment: thanks, yes it seems this [case statement uses pdftotext](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/b6be66e8851f6b2b775eec2782e83af8340bfba0/ranger/data/scope.sh#L76).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, ranger uses `pdftotext` to preview PDFs by default, but the answer to your title question is: `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh` dictates how files are previewed.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.